# Ioncube encoding error while installing udropship extension in local server

Tags: magento, ioncube

I have tried to install the udropship extension to my local server.Following error occurs

> Fatal error: The file
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\app\code\community\Unirgy\DropshipMicrosite\Helper\Protected.php
>   was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5 and cannot run under PHP
>   5.5 or PHP 5.6. Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for either PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4
>   or PHP 5.5. in Unknown on line 0

I have updated the latest version of Ioncube Loader although same error occurs repeatedly.Below the screenshot of loader installed successfully.[image]

Can any one help? I couldn't figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The message from the Loader is surely ***very*** precise:

> [your file] cannot run under PHP 5.5 or PHP 5.6. Please ask the
>   provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube
>   Encoder for either PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5.

So, you should... "ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for either PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5."

There is further an alternative that while unstated, logically follows from the statement that your file "cannot run under PHP 5.5 or PHP 5.6", which is NOT to use PHP 5.5 or 5.6, i.e. use PHP 5.4 instead.